# Java regex not compiling

Tags: java, regex

I have the code

```
private String regexHHMM = "^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$";
```

The code does not compile with the error "Unclosed Character class"

This must be something very basic, is there any particular escaping I should be using, also I am mainly interested on WHY it cannot be accepted by the java compiler.

UPDATE: I have tried

```
Pattern.quote("^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$");
```

And now it compiles, but the regex does not match the HH:MM format now...

Comment: `Pattern.quote` is for escaping all special character in the String, so that when it is compiled, the regex will match the characters in the original String literally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the initial open square bracket inside of your pattern.

```
^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
  ^
```

Should be:

```
^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Comment: Good one, and I guess the reason it does not compile is because the java compiler parses every string?

Comment: @Gary: The character class can be nested arbitrarily deep in Java. It's called character class union.

Comment: @JuanAntonioGomezMoriano Are you sure it "does not compile"?  Your declaration of `regexHHMM` is just a `String` variable initialized with a string literal.  As far as I know, it isn't parsed as a regex until runtime when you call `Pattern.compile` or some other methods.  What exactly is the "compiler"'s behavior?

Comment: @ajb: The regex is compiled at run time by `Pattern` class (implicitly via some method in String class or explicitly), and the OP's regex return a `PatternSyntaxException`.

Comment: @nhahtdh Right, "at run time" ... but OP is saying it's the compiler doing it, and asking if the "java compiler parses every string"...